# xmlreader.value to string conversion in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, console-application

I'm trying to read font (my own, defined by special class) from XML file.

The funny thing is I can read numbers and parse them to int, or even get the hex value, "chop" it on three or for parts to getting ARGB values, but I can't to the simplest part :)

My xml reader don't want to set values to strings:

```
myFont.name = xReader.Value.ToString();
```

The Value of `myFont.name` i always empty, even if I'm trying to chop it to single characters and adding one by one to `myFont.name` string (my desperate decision)

However, as I said, I can read int values using the same way:

```
myFont.size = int.Parse(xReader.Value.ToString());
//returns correct value for the size
```

I can also display it in console window:

```
Console.Writeline(xReader.Value); //returns correct string
myFont.name=xReader.Value;
Console.Writeline(myFont.name.ToString()); //returns empty string
```

Any ideas?

edit:
Font Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6.entities
{
public class PDFFont
{

    public int size { get; set; }
    public int ColorR { get; set; }
    public int ColorG { get; set; }
    public int ColorB { get; set; }
    public int ColorA { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
}
```

edit2:
switch case construction:

```
 while (Xread.MoveToNextAttribute())
                            {
                                entities.PDFFont newFont = new entities.PDFFont();
                                switch (Xread.Name)
                                {
                                    case "name":

                                        newFont.name = Xread.Value.ToString();
//returns null
                                        break;
                                    case "size": newFont.size = int.Parse(Xread.Value.ToString()); break;
//returns null, however before I create method below worked ok

                                    case "color":

                                        colorCreator nColor = new colorCreator(Xread.Value);
                                        newFont.ColorR = nColor.R;
                                        newFont.ColorG = nColor.G;
                                        newFont.ColorB = nColor.B;
                                        newFont.ColorA = nColor.A;
//works perfectly, values are transfer corectly 

                                        break;
                                }
```

I also tried to set this value outside switch case construction, on another object and it works. So something is wrong with part written above.
I have just put console.writeline("were hear!"); between newFont.name = xRead.Value and break, and it shows itself. So I know that case "name" were found in my xml file.

Comment: could you: show the xml, show how you are reading the XML (or at least, the specific part which is leading to the problem) and the property definition of myfont?

Comment: can you show the defn of myFont?  you've basically shown its a problem in the setter of the name property.

Comment: Are you overriding `ToString()` anywhere?

Comment: I just noticed that I can't place even simple string
    myFont.name = "some text";
    //value is still empty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not do anything creative, so I decided to rebuild this construction. It works thanks for MoveToAttribute(string) method.

```
     try
                        {                                
                            Xread.MoveToAttribute("name");
                            newFont.name = Xread.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        catch { newFont.name = "default"; }

                        try
                        {
                            Xread.MoveToAttribute("size");
                            newFont.size = int.Parse(Xread.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        catch { newFont.size = 12; }
                        try
                        {
                             Xread.MoveToAttribute("color");
                             colorCreator nColor = new colorCreator(Xread.Value);
                                            newFont.ColorR = nColor.R;
                                            newFont.ColorG = nColor.G;
                                            newFont.ColorB = nColor.B;
                                            newFont.ColorA = nColor.A;
                                        }
                                        catch {
                                            newFont.ColorR = 0;
                                            newFont.ColorG = 0;
                                            newFont.ColorB = 0;
                                            newFont.ColorA = 255;
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are clearing the content of the name attribute somewhere. Put a breakpoint and go step by step.

Comment: I did a breakpoint on line with myFont.name = "something"; The value of myFont.name is null.

Comment: I see that you are using threading tasks. Are you using that name attribute inside a task function?

Comment: yes. But, some of them are working correctly. I can add that everything is working in "switch case" construction